# onTouch event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am relatively new to React-Native.

I was trying to implement onTouch event but for some reason this doesn't seem to be working.

for example in this code

```
    <View style={[container1,this.state.increased ? {backgroundColor: "#B4EEB4"} : null,this.state.decreased ? {backgroundColor: "#ffe5e5"} : null]} onPress={() => this.touched(this.props.key)}>
                    <View style={upperRow}>
                    <Text style={sno}> {this.props.no} </Text>
                    <Image 
                        source={{uri: "https://coincap.io/images/coins/" + this.props.coinName + ".png"}}
                        style={img}
                        /> 
                        <Text style={coinSymbol}>{this.props.coinShortName}</Text>
                        <Text style={coinPrice}>${this.props.coinPrice}</Text>
                        <View style={percentageBox}>
                        <Text style={this.props.percentChange < 0 ? percentChangeMinus : percentChangePlus }>{this.props.percentChange}%</Text>
                        </View>
                        </View>

                <Display enable={stateToDisplay}>
                    <View style={statisticsContainer}>
                              <Text style={marketCap}>Cap: {this.props.marketCap}B </Text>
                             <Text style={seperator1}>|</Text>
                             <Text style={vwapData}>24vwap: {this.props.vwapData} </Text>
                    </View>
                </Display> 

             </View>
```

Here

```
View style={[container1,this.state.increased ? {backgroundColor: "#B4EEB4"} : null,this.state.decreased ? {backgroundColor: "#ffe5e5"} : null]} onPress={() => this.touched(this.props.key)}>
```

I am passing this `onPress` event

```
onPress={() => this.touched(this.props.key)
```

which I expect should have called/run the function touched here

lass  CoinCard extends Component {

```
state = {
    increased: false,
    decreased: false,
    selectedPostId: "none"
}



componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (this.props.coinPrice != nextProps.coinPrice ) {
       if (this.props.coinPrice > nextProps.coinPrice) {
          this.setState({decreased: true, increased: false})
       }

       if (this.props.coinPrice < nextProps.coinPrice) {
        this.setState({increased: true, decreased: false})
       }
    }
}

touched = (id) => {
    this.setState({selectedPostId: id})
    console.log("inside touched")
}
```

**[Question]** But clicking on the container is doing nothing at the moment. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while in React Native View does not have an onPress prop, it does have an onTouchStart, onTouchEnd events. This however will be called even if you touch the children inside the view, so its not a good way if you want the touch to be exclusively to the container outside the content in the view.

So you can either have onTouchStart and handle your onPress logic there, or wrap your entire view in a TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight or TouchableWithoutFeedback and handle the onPress on that.

[More on React Native Touchables](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches#touchables)

Answer (score 1):

`View` component does not provide an `onPress` prop. You can either use  [`TouchableHighlight`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight) or [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity).